# How to schedule tasks in sequence using result of previous task with schedule to execute once?

Tags: python, queue, subprocess, schedule

Code below has to execute all tasks in sequence using result of a previous tasks and execute script once. Code is correct but it does nothing. Note that with os.system code execute scripts which contains shutil.move or os.rename functions. os.system('filename.py) function has been tested and runs smoothly with schedule module.
I use pypi schedule project enter link description here][1

```
import schedule
import time
import os


def job_that_executes_once():
 os.system('C:\FB_GR_MEMBERS_AUTO\FB_GR_SCRIPTS\1CODEOSORSHUTIL.py')

schedule.every().day.at('9:39').do(job_that_executes_once)

def job_that_executes_once():
 os.system('C:\FB_GR_MEMBERS_AUTO\FB_GR_SCRIPTS\2CODERENAME.py') 

schedule.every().day.at('9:40').do(job_that_executes_once)

def job_that_executes_once():
  os.system('C:\FB_GR_MEMBERS_AUTO\FB_GR_SCRIPTS\3CODERENAME.py') 

schedule.every().day.at('9:41').do(job_that_executes_once)

while True:
  schedule.run_pending()
time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: Have you tried running `os.system('C:\FB_GR_MEMBERS_AUTO\FB_GR_SCRIPTS\1CODEOSORSHUTIL.py'` directly instead of having it inside of the scheduled job? It really looks like it should actually be `os.system('C:\\FB_GR_MEMBERS_AUTO\\FB_GR_SCRIPTS\\1CODEOSORSHUTIL.py'`

Comment: It works with os.system separately and perfectly functions with periodic open processes combining python scripts with os.system to run on predefined time and periodiocity. I can not change sequence of codes to be automated.